# Searching PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: powershell, pdf, itext

I have been using [iTextSharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/) to search PDF's but I have come across a problem.  The PDF in question has bullet points like:

- This is a test line 1
- This is a test line 2

I am trying to search each pdf for a phrase - in this example the phrase would be 'test line'.  The code I'm using is:

```
for ($page = 1; $page -le $reader.NumberOfPages; $page++)
        {
$strategy = new-object  iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy
$currentText = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($reader, $page, $strategy)
```

However this does not find the phrase 'test line'.  When I looked at the results of each page iTextSharp was searching it looked like:

```
- This    is      a   test    line    1
```

```
- This    is      a   test    line    2
```

Is there anyway to extract the text from the PDF and exclude the formatting?

Many thanks
Paul

Comment: I'd love to help, but I don't know how to install iTextSharp.  Could you give us a link to the installer?

Comment: Please don't link to the Sourceforge page. iText Software has moved away from that site, as many, many other open source projects have done. The official website is http://itextpdf.com, documentation on http://developers.itextpdf.com, sources and downloads are on GitHub: http://github.com/itext/itextsharp and we're also on NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/

Comment: Please share the PDF in question to allow reproducing the issue and analyzing it.